# Typescript - is Rename symbol possible when "keyof" is used?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, dsl, template-literals

I'm trying the concept of using TypeScript with "AsciiDoc" as a DSL.

```js
////
interface Login {
  "User name":  "OK" | "KO"
  "Password":   string
  "Sign In":    any
}
interface Agenda {
  "Message":    "Welcome" | "Invalid credentials"
}
////

AsciiDoc `

# AC: I can sign in with valid credentials

. given `<Login>` 

. when I set ${ "User name" }, ${ "Password" } and apply ${ "Sign In" }

. then I expect `<Agenda>` and ${ "Message" }

`

CSV `

,===
`<[ L ["User name"] , L ["Password"] , A ["Message"]          ]>`
${[ "OK"            , "valid"        , "Welcome"              ]}
${[ "KO"            , "invalid"      , "Invalid credentials"  ]}
,===

`

////
type L = Login
type A = Agenda

declare function AsciiDoc ( _: _ ): typeof DSL
declare function DSL <Context> ( _: _, ...$: (keyof Context)[] ): typeof DSL
declare function CSV ( _: _ ) :( <Header extends string[]> ( _: _, ...rows: [...Header][] ) => string )

type _ = TemplateStringsArray
////
```

And here I am missing Rename symbol support in the "AsciiDoc" part - for`${ "User name" }` by example. I think, it is related to the `keyof Context` within `declare function DSL` ...

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5JvW)

The question is - how can I achieve Rename support **everywhere** ?

Or how to change the concept to achieve **maximum** TypeScript **TypeSafety**, **Autocomplete** and **Rename Symbol support ?**

**Or** maybe you know **similar DSL "tool" - already done ?**

Regards.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a *very* hard time understanding this question. Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to do, what you expect to happen and where, and what is happening instead?  I don't know what "Rename Symbol support" means... what "symbol" is this?  Not a JS `symbol`, surely?  Do you mean something else?

Comment: @jcalz thank you - I replaced images with plain text version. In TS Playground, pls try Rename symbol (F2) - `User name` or `OK` from `CSV` section - it is renamed in `interface Login` also. But when you try Rename `User name` from `AsciiDoc` section - it is not renamed in `interface Login` as expected. Is it more clear now? Regards.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now... this is specifically an IntelliSense thing.  I don't have any insight, sorry.  Other than maybe [ms/TS#49070](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49070) ‍♂️.  Perhaps someone else will come along who can help!

Comment: @jcalz thank you. do you think it is because of tagged template literal or because `keyof` in `declare function DSL` ?

Comment: I don't have any insight, sorry.